# How do I use react-use-fuse?

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules

Can anyone provide a full working example of how to use react-use-fuse in reactjs?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-fuse

I'm trying but am getting an error on the last line

Error: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Main app code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MyComponent from './Search'

const customers = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Customer A', email: 'aa@aa.com'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Customer B', email: 'mm@mm.com'}
  ]

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent customers={customers} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Search Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFuse } from 'react-use-fuse';

function MyComponent({customers}){

  // This is Fuse specific options. Read more at
  // https://fusejs.io/#examples
  const options = {
      keys: ["name", "email"]
  }

  // Setup the Hook.
  const { result, search, term } = useFuse({
      data: customers,
      options
  });

  return (
      <div>
          <input
              onChange={e => search(e.target.value)}
              value={term}
              placeholder="Search for a customer..."
          />

          {result.map(customer => (
              <div>
                  {customer.name} - {customer.email}
              </div>
          ))}
      </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the README](https://github.com/MartinL83/react-use-fuse#readme)? Also what have you tried?

Comment: Yes I looked at the readme, Tried using the the code provided but it throws an error

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Comment: updated with code

Answer (score 0):

You should import `useFuse` without the curly brackets: `import useFuse from 'react-use-fuse';`. In the library, the hook is a default export which doesn't require the curly brackets when imported into your code.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import useFuse from 'react-use-fuse';

function MyComponent({customers}){
  // This is Fuse specific options. Read more at
  // https://fusejs.io/#examples
  const options = {
      keys: ["name", "email"]
  }

  // Setup the Hook.
  const { result, search, term } = useFuse({
      data: customers,
      options
  });

  return (
      <div>
          <input
              onChange={e => search(e.target.value)}
              value={term}
              placeholder="Search for a customer..."
          />

          {result.map(customer => (
              <div>
                  {customer.name} - {customer.email}
              </div>
          ))}
      </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

For further information on importing ES6 default exports, [check the official docs](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_default-exports-one-per-module).

### UPDATE

Regarding the other undefined error (`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in Fuse.js`) after the `react-use-fuse` import was resolved. I am not able to reproduce the same error in this [CodeSandbox attempt](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-bhabha-8o9h8?file=/src/Search.js). Perhaps there is something else going on.

Comment: Done that, but now I'm getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in Fuse.js

Comment: Ah well `customers` is undefined, you need to supply some data to fuse.js. I will add the example customers, but you will need to add your own data

Comment: Is that not what I'm doing in App.js, and then passing it to MyComponent?

Comment: Do you happen to have the line where this new undefined error shows up?

Comment: It seems to think the error is in fuse.js itself, with e.value